# Binding javascript events inside iframe sandbox in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, dom-events, sandbox

I'm trying to make the following work in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/3es621uz/1/

HTML:

```
<iframe src="about:blank" id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin"></iframe>
```

Javascript:

```
var b, i;
i = document.getElementById('iframe');
b = i.contentDocument.createElement('button');
b.innerHTML = 'Click me!';
b.addEventListener('click', function() {
  return alert('Used to work!');
});
i.contentDocument.body.appendChild(b);
```

Clicking the button used to show the alert in Chrome at some point. It still does in Firefox but doesn't work in Safari. Is there any way for me to bind events in the iframe from outside without allowing scripts inside it to execute?

Comment: Chrome says: _Blocked script execution in 'about:blank' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set_

Comment: Well yes, but I don't want to set `allow-scripts` because that would allow any Javascript to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Related document: https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/pull/7153, and I found that Chrome had changed its behaviour since version 71.

The same problem should happen when trying to post messages:

```js
iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener('message', console.log);
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage('what', '*');

// => throw "Blocked script execution in 'about:blank' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set"
// but it worked after Chrome 71
```

Answer (score 0):

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) mentions:

> When the embedded document has the same origin as the main page, it is strongly discouraged to use both `allow-scripts` and `allow-same-origin` at the same time, as that allows the embedded document to programmatically remove the sandbox attribute. Although it is accepted, this case is no more secure than not using the sandbox attribute.

You can't both include arbitrary (untrusted) content *and* programmatically control the frame using `sandbox`.